# Write methods without lambda

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the lesson we went through Spring and I want to understand this code

I have code:

```
 public class  TopicService {

    List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Topic("1", "Petya", "Java"),
            new Topic("2", "Vasya", "Javascript"),
            new Topic("3", "Fedya", "Php")));

  

    public Topic getTopic(String id) {
        return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
    }
   }

    public void deleteTopic(String id) {
        topics.removeIf(t -> t.getId().equals(id));
    }
}
```

I have not studied and am not familiar with lambda yet.
Help me write these methods in a regular format like here:

```
   public void updateTopic(String id, Topic topic) {
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++) {
            Topic t = topics.get(i);
            if (t.getId().equals(id)) {
                topics.set(i, topic);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an IDE? It might help un-lambda-ing the code

Comment: @luk2302 The code is correct and working, I just want to describe it in a more understandable version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getTopic:

```
public Topic getTopic(String id) {
    for(Topic tp : topics) {
       if (tp.getId().equals(id)){
          return tp;
       }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

deleteTopic:

```
public void deleteTopic(String id) {
   for(Topic tp : topics) {
      if (tp.getId().equals(id)){
         topics.remove(tp);
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream simply prepares your collection for various methods that accept a functional interface as argument (lambda is simply an implementation of a functional interface). Read about Java Stream methods to get the understanding.

```
public Topic getTopic(String id) {
    for (Topic topic : topics)
        if (topic.getId().equals(id)) return topic;

    return null;
}

public void deleteTopic(String id) {
    for (Topic topic : topics)
        if (topic.getId().equals(id)) topics.remove(topic);
}
```

I wanted you to figure it out yourself, but since you asked...

Comment: Can you write deleteTopic method and i select you answer bro <3

Comment: public Topic getTopic(String id) {
        for (Topic topic : topics) {
            if (topic.getId().equals(id)) {
                return topic;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Is not correct or need do:  public Topic getTopic(String id) {
        for (Topic topic : topics) {
            if (topic.getId().equals(id)) {
                return topic;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: I've corrected the answer, please accept it again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow :)

Suppose you are passing your list of topics ("topics" instead of "topic")as a parameter you could do :

```
topics.stream()
  .filter(n -> n.getId().equals(id)equals("Android"))
  .forEach(n -> topics.set(n.getId(), n););

.stream()
```

is uded to manipulate sequences of elements

```
.filter(condition)
```

will give you the elements of this "stream" on which ids are equal to "Android" and then

```
.forEach
```

will make your update for these elements.

You'll maybe have to make some modifications to your code to be correct but here is the idea.
Don't hesitate to accept as an answer if it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getTopic:

```
     public Topic getTopic(String id) {
                     for(Topic tp : topics) {
                         if (tp.getId().equals(id)){
                             return tp;
                         }
                     }
                    return null;
                    }
```

and for deleteTopic :

```
public void deleteTopic(String id) {
         for(Topic tp : topics) {
             if (tp.getId().equals(id)){
                 topics.remove(tp);
                 break;
             }
         } 
        }
```